# Transferring data from one process to another

Tags: file, memory

I have two processes **A** and **B** both written in different languages. **A** reads a file does some processing on it and keeps it in its memory for a while. I want to transfer the processed data (an array buffer) to process **B** as fast as possible to do some more processing on it and finally return it to process **A**.

I have thought of three different ways to do it:

1. Writing and reading to files: process **A** writes the data to a file that process **B** reads from and vice-versa.
2. Using *MemoryMappedFile/mmap*: process **A** creates a shared memory page using *mmap* and the reading / writing happens there instead.
3. Using *ReadProcessMemory*: process **B** directly reads the data from process **A** virtual memory and vice-versa.

Some numbers I got from testing these three methods for a data of **~500mb**:

1. File reading: **~150ms**, file writing: **~7000ms**
2. *MemoryMappedFile/mmap* reading: **~2600ms**, mmap writing: **~2100ms**
3. Memory reading / writing: **~250ms** each

Some notes:

- I have limited control over process **A** but full control over process **B**. I can't free the data from memory in process **A** for example.
- Injecting code from **B** inside **A** to do the processing there is not possible.
- The data in process **B** will be processed sequentially.

Seems like direct memory reading & writing is the fastest but I believe it also requires double the RAM (both processes would hold a copy of the data) and might cause issues with permissions which is not desirable.

Do you guys have a better idea on how to do this? Any tips to make the data transfer as fast as possible?

Answer (score 0):

A clean and common way would is to use localhost sockets. One process writes the desired data in there and the other reads it. It is definitely cleaner than your first approach, but slower than the other two. But it is definitely portable and won't make things too complicated. Also the other process can even respond!

Comment: That's a great idea, definitely better than communicating using regular files. But sending the data between the two processes *as fast as possible* is the most important criteria in this case.

Comment: Shared memory should be the fastest, assuming you don't have to allocate it first. For example use mmap for allocating the array buffer in the first place. I think `ReadProcessMemory` is not portable, because it is windows specific and different linux systems use different approaches to archive this.

If you only use the C program to calculate something, you can use ctypes (python library) to run C code from you python process.